# How to delete a single column cell in an org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In Excel etc it is possible to delete a cell in a column and have the cells below it "shift up" without affecting the content of the other columns. I haven't found a command for this in `org-mode`, is there one?

Example: In the following table I want to delete the cell `Banana`.

```
| Cars  | Fruits |
|-------+--------|
| Volvo | Apple  |
| Saab  | Banana |
| Ford  | Pear   |
```

This should be the result:

```
| Cars  | Fruits |
|-------+--------|
| Volvo | Apple  |
| Saab  | Pear   |
| Ford  |        |
```

Now ideally if I were to additionally delete `Volvo` the table would look like this:

```
| Cars | Fruits |
|------+--------|
| Saab | Apple  |
| Ford | Pear   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function I wrote,

```
(defun org-table-collapse-cell ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion ;; Save point
    (org-table-blank-field) ;; Blank the cell
    (while (progn ;; Swap blank cell with a cell under it until the blank is at the bottom.
         (org-table--move-cell 'down)
         (org-table-align)
         (org-table-check-inside-data-field))))
  (org-table-next-field))
```

It's very rough and calling it on `Volvo` and `Banana` yields

```
| Cars | Fruits |
|------+--------|
| Saab | Apple  |
| Ford | Pear   |
|      |        |
```

Which, I think should be enough you can delete the empty row yourself.

Comment: Rolling your own seems like a good solution. I made a small change which handles the error from org-table--move-cell and also restores the point a bit better than save-excursion.

(defun org-table-collapse-cell ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pt (point)))
    (org-table-blank-field)
    (condition-case nil
        (while (org-table-check-inside-data-field)
          (org-table--move-cell 'down)
          (org-table-align))
      (user-error nil))
    (goto-char pt)))